# How to check if a transaction is still in the blockchain?

Tags: blockchain, web3js, proof-of-work, forks, uncle-blocks

Say we want to confirm that a value transaction `tx` has reached certain finality, which we define as waiting for 12 block confirmations. We do this to drop the probability of `tx` getting lost due a fork or it getting included in an uncle block.

The examples I've seen use `getBlock` and/or `getTransaction` first to make sure `tx` was mined in a block.

They then wait until 12 new blocks have been mined and seem to use `getTransactionReceipt` to check if `tx` is still in the blockchain.

- Is there some functional difference in this context between using `getTransaction` and `getTransactionReceipt` to check if `tx` still has `blockNumber`? The implementations don't seem to use any of the additional data returned by `getTransactionReceipt` making it slightly confusing.
- Lets say a fork happened or `tx` got into an orphaned block before 12 confirmations. Does this mean that `getTransaction` and `getTransactionReceipt` will return null for the transaction or how is this reflected in these calls?

Comment: Can you post your final solution?

Answer (score 8):

No, there is no difference in this case-- they are essentially equivalent. If the tx is orphaned, they should return `null`, but you should still check the block number because it may have been added to the new chain later than you expect, giving less probability of finality.

Comment: What about the `tx` getting lost in a fork? Will the methods still return `null` or the block number be `null`? Not sure if `tx` getting orphaned covers the fork case.

Comment: Could you also please elaborate on how the block number should be checked? Does this mean `tx`'s initial block number can change between the first and last calls (after 12 blocks)? And furthermore, does this mean it's recommended to wait for additional blocks to cover the difference to reach 12 confirmations?

Comment: A fork and being orphaned are essentially the same, althlough a fork generally implies a much larger reorganization depth. As long as `(tx.blockNumber - eth.blockNumber) > 12`, you have 12 confirmations.