# Transactions from myetherwallet.com not going through

Tags: transactions, blockchain, myetherwallet

I created yesterday a wallet at https://www.myetherwallet.com, however I tried to send some small amounts into three different wallets but none is going through.

If you look at etherscan.io the ether seems still to be at my wallet:

https://etherscan.io/address/0xac541c3c698a729ebf6c42419860cdddabd622a6

However the amounts to be sent are staying pending and the time when it was sent is changing always to a few seconds. Sometimes they are not showing at all and I need to refresh the page to see them again.

Are these approx. 2 Eth now lost? It's been almost a day since I sent my first amount.

What about the rest in my wallet, how can I prevent losing my Ether there?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Your Ether won't be lost. But your transaction [can](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/11438/can-a-transaction-get-lost). If it does, you won't have spent the Ether at all. This prevents double spending, but it also means that the existence of your transaction is probabilistic. You can try increasing the gas price to make your transaction more appealing to miners.

Comment: Thanks for that! I entered a really high gas price and suddenly all my transactions are sent